# VSCode Rest client - how to set variable to variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, rest-client

Using VSCode Rest Client - How do you pass the value of a variable between variables?

```
@varA = “123”
@varB = “234”
@varFinal = varA
```

currently it doesn’t pass the value, it sets varFinal to the static string ‘varA’ - I want it to be ‘123’

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to include variable inside double bracket like "{{variableName}}".  In the above scenario, you could change the expression as shown below

```
@varA = 123
@varB = 234
@varFinal = {{varA}}
```

In the below example, I am storing "swapi.co" in variable "host".  Further I am assigning "host" variable to "host1" and using in my http request.

```
@host = swapi.co
@host1 = {{host}}

GET https://{{host1}}/api/planets/ HTTP/1.1
```